# Listing all term items alphabetically / sorting loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, query-posts, terms

I have my own custom post type and it has its own taxonomy and terms.

Whenever user visits http://example.com/mytaxonomy/myterm I want the page to display all items within this term alphabetically.

I've created taxonomy-mytaxonomy.php file where I list the items using this loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    the_title(); 
endwhile;
```

The question is - how to output these items in alphabetical order? query_posts() mixes these with regular posts.